# Graphic sound analyzer of microphone

Tags: android, audio, microphone

I am building on an app which has a function which records the sound which comes in the microphone. It would be handy to give a **graphical view of the incoming sound**, like http://www.filebuzz.com/software_screenshot/full/10920-Audio_Edit.gif for example.

I searched a little bit for a tutorial online, but the only thing I found was Audalyzer, but it is difficult for me to get a grip on it, it also is using the whole interface and not clear how to implement it as a widget...

Maybe somebody knows a good tutorial or example code on this?

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to use a Fast Fourier Transform for this.
I'd try jTransforms: https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms
The blog here: http://trueharmoniccolours.co.uk/Blog/ gives a good introduction into what the FFT does and how you can turn it into a chart.  I fear that by the end of this you'll understand FFTs though...

Comment: Judging by the link in the question the OP wants to plot the audio waveform, not a spectrogram. So an FFT should not be necessary.

Comment: Well it can either in these forms: http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00UvBEaqIRHdbK/EL-Sound-Activated-T-Shirt.jpg or http://web.hcpss.org/~paul_wiedorn/types/soundengineeringjf_files/soundPicture.jpg. I think the basics to start from to plot one of those are the same or am I wrong?